# Linq query by parameters

Tags: c#, database, linq, nhibernate, group-by

I am trying to implement a new method for querying using NHibernate and Linq. The method is:

```
public object Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression, Expression<Func<T, object>> groupExpressionKeySelector, Expression<Func<object, IEnumerable<T>, object>> resultSelector)
{
        var results = Session.Query<T>().Where(whereExpression).GroupBy(groupExpressionKeySelector, resultSelector).ToList();
        return results;
}
```

And the call is like:

```
    Expression<Func<Serial, bool>> whereExpression = serial => serial.Status == Status.Ok;
Expression<Func<Serial, object>> groupExpressionKeySelector = serial => serial.Type.Code;
Expression<Func<object, IEnumerable<Serial>, object>> groupExpressionResultSelector = (key, q) => new { Id = key, Quantity = q.Count() };

var results = this.SerialRepository.Query(whereExpression, groupExpressionKeySelector, groupExpressionResultSelector);
```

The problem is that sentence raises the exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' with:

{"Ningún método genérico 'GroupBy' para el tipo 'System.Linq.Enumerable' es compatible con los argumentos normales y de tipo proporcionados. No se deben proporcionar argumentos de tipo si el método no es genérico. "}

It seems like it is not expecting typed arguments...Do you know what is happening? Without the parameter resultSelector everything works..

Comment: It looks to me you try to duplicate the Linq queryable API into your own. Are you really needing that? Why not using directly `IQueryable` objects from caller? Because it is the business logic? If yes, it should not either be able to supply filtering/grouping/projecting logic, that does belongs to a repository, not to a business logic.

Comment: And you should provide a translated version of the exception message. (With a disclaimer like 'approximated translation' if you wish.)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [my comment](/questions/35890196/linq-query-by-parameters#comment59463358_35890196), I doubt your case has a good design.

Anyway, I suspect the trouble is `object` typing for key is too broad and requires to be more specific. Maybe your current typing prevents the compiler to choose the right `GroupBy` overload. Adds more generic parameters to your method.

```
public object Query<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> groupExpressionKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TKey, IEnumerable<T>, object>> resultSelector)
{
        var results = Session.Query<T>()
            .Where(whereExpression)
            .GroupBy(groupExpressionKeySelector, resultSelector)
            .ToList();
        return results;
}
```

Then, supposing `serial.Type.Code`is a `string`:

```
Expression<Func<Serial, bool>> whereExpression =
    serial => serial.Status == Status.Ok;
Expression<Func<Serial, string>> groupExpressionKeySelector =
    serial => serial.Type.Code;
Expression<Func<string, IEnumerable<Serial>, object>> groupExpressionResultSelector = 
    (key, q) => new { Id = key, Quantity = q.Count() };

var results = this.SerialRepository.Query(whereExpression,
    groupExpressionKeySelector, groupExpressionResultSelector);
```

But it may not be enough. You may need to go full generic. Due to anonymous typing, it requires supplying `resultSelector` directly:

```
public List<TResult> Query<TKey, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> groupExpressionKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TKey, IEnumerable<T>, TResult>> resultSelector)
{
        var results = Session.Query<T>()
            .Where(whereExpression)
            .GroupBy(groupExpressionKeySelector, resultSelector)
            .ToList();
        return results;
}
```

Then, still supposing `serial.Type.Code`is a `string`:

```
Expression<Func<Serial, bool>> whereExpression =
    serial => serial.Status == Status.Ok;
Expression<Func<Serial, string>> groupExpressionKeySelector =
    serial => serial.Type.Code;

var results = this.SerialRepository.Query(whereExpression,
    groupExpressionKeySelector, 
    (key, q) => new { Id = key, Quantity = q.Count() });
```